# how can I write to my own processes stdin while also reading from stdin on another thread

Tags: rust

I'm reading from stdin on one thread and performing logic based on the input.

I have a case where from another thread I'd like to write to my **own** processes `STDIN` (to be handled by the existing logic in that other thread's context without modifying any code if possible).

Is this possible? Not sure how to accomplish this.

I tried (unsuccessfully) things like this:

```
std::thread::spawn(|| {
    // my own stdin
                let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    
                while true {
                    // write to my own stdin - doesn't work!
                    stdin.write_all(b"Hello, world!\n");
                    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Neither `Stdin` nor `StdinLock` implements `Write`. However, this sounds a bit like an XY problem. Why are you attempting to communicate between threads using stdin?

Comment: its a hack to proxy a debugged process (with a minimal server) which regularly is listening on stdin for commands from an external tool. i want to chain the stdins (I'm on mac so couldn't write to /proc/.../fd/ of the debugged process). if you have a better way of writing to a STDIN of an arbitrary process let me know

Comment: So if I'm understanding it correctly. IPC where one process can insert itself between 2 others? E.g., you have 3 processes, (a) which talks to (b) and then you want to be able to "insert" (c) to capture the output of (a) _process it_ and then (c) forwards it to (b)?

Comment: A -> B -> C where B->C is over stdin and I want to debug C. I spent hours looking for ways to forward  B -> stdin Debug(C), but wasn't able to find a way to do that. I instead thought to compile C to forward to stdin of my debugged C which is listening on IPC and writing to stdin Self (in the debugged context that is)

Comment: in c++ i saw a way to create a file which is forwarded to stdin of the current running process. I coulnd't find how to do that in rust

Comment: Have you tried using e.g. [`File::from_raw_fd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html#tymethod.from_raw_fd)/[`File::from_raw_handle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/io/trait.FromRawHandle.html#tymethod.from_raw_handle)? I must say, I've only tried using `from_raw_fd` in the context of stdout, not stdin.